# Where is core animation defined?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I can't figure out where core animation on iPhone OS 3.1.2 is defined.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, it is recommended that you use

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then add the QuartzCore framework to your project to make use of low-level Core Animation classes.

Even though all it does is effectively import CoreAnimation.h on the iPhone, on the Mac QuartzCore also includes Core Image and Core Video, so Apple may add these and other capabilities to the QuartzCore framework on the iPhone in the future.  Frankly, Apple recommends using the above include for Core Animation, so I defer to them.

Answer (score 4):

it is defined in QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h